# Pandas: Filter 14000 rows from a data frame consisting 300000 rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame df1 consisting of 14000 person id. I have another data frame df2 consisting of 300000 data of ids and other attributes. I need to match the 14000 id's of df1 to the 300000 id's of df2 and extract the whole row of those 14000 ids.

```
df1 personUuid
0   99afae32-1486-47db-825e-6695f742eb86
1   bb22ca94-1f4b-435c-98ff-bd6f02a6b42b
2   ecfdc560-cc97-4525-8d1e-e3536793ef6e
3   8fbe1e4f-ae1e-4949-afd9-b120f6ae3762
4   d83dc0c4-26e6-4126-926d-7b84913bca13
... ...
14367   23592455-47a2-47ef-9d21-a283ae50988d
14368   1adecd7e-a0c2-4c35-bef1-75569f3b57fe
14369   e96f6eb4-d823-47b4-bd03-755e8f685e8f
14370   c87156e2-9610-40f4-a75a-17435d9fa91f
14371   70f08fd1-c595-4d01-886d-ed586a77c1d1


personUuid  firstName   middleName  lastName    emails  urls    locations   currentTitles   currentCompanies    education   ... count_currentTitles fullName    li_clean    gh_clean    tw_clean    fb_clean    email_clean email_clean1    email_clean2    email_clean3
0   ab92fa98-2427-461d-87ac-31a440b6e1ae    
1   658c57b9-457a-4e97-8b1c-10ab45655518    
2   7da5a858-3c20-46c0-b728-23e64352094d    
3   9c14f2b6-a81a-49af-85d4-d4cf76001f07
```

Similarly, I have the second data frame with 300K person ids and attributes like fullname, emails, location, etc.

need to match those 14K ids to 300 K and display all the attributes of the 14K only.

Comment: I hope those aren't real people's personal information you've just publicized as part of this question (presumably without their consent).

Comment: Yes please remove/mask the names if they're real people.

Comment: Removed it. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you looked at [`pandas.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)?

Comment: Or [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), or [`pandas.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)?

Comment: I changed the personUuid in df1 to 'match' and the used  : df2.loc[df2.personUuid.isin(df1['match'])]. It works but only shows me 7854 rows instead of 14371. Any clue why that happens?

Comment: Do you have duplicates? Are you 100% positive that df1 is a strict subset of df2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a merge with an inner join as given below:

```
df1['personUuid'] = df1['personUuid'].str.strip()
df2['personUuid'] = df2['personUuid'].str.strip()
df = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, how='inner', on=['personUuid'])
```

Comment: I tried the method you suggested, the result gives me 7854 rows instead of 14371.

Comment: Then you have some extra characters, space etc. which is why the match is not happening

Comment: Check the edited answer and try using `strip()` first

Comment: Tried using the strip method but it still gives the same result.